# Understand jQuery Tutorial Module Pattern example

Tags: jquery, code-organization, module-pattern

Considering the last code fragment (reported below) about module pattern published in the [Code Organization section of the Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/), I'm trying to understand some aspect of the module in the example:

- The variable declarations (`$items`, `$container`...) are separated by `;` while the function declarations (`createContainer`, `buildUrl`, `showItem`, ....) are separated by `,`. Why? Is there a bracket problem?
- Why the name of the first three variables (`$items`, `$container` and `$currentItem`) starts with `$`? Does this imply a naming convention (since `javascript` allows the character `$`) used to identify a DOM fragment variable or is there some other reason?
- Why the function `createContainer` is declared using `var` while the other functions  (`buildUrl`, `showItem`,...) doesn't have `var`?

// Using the module pattern for a jQuery feature
    $( document ).ready(function() {

```
var feature = (function() {

var $items = $("#myFeature li");
var $container = $("<div class='container'></div>");
var $currentItem = null;
var urlBase = "/foo.php?item=";
var createContainer = function() {
  var $i = $( this );
  var $c = $container.clone().appendTo( $i );
  $i.data( "container", $c );
},
buildUrl = function() {
  return urlBase + $currentItem.attr("id");
},
showItem = function() {
  var $currentItem = $( this );
  getContent( showContent );
},
showItemByIndex = function( idx ) {
  $.proxy( showItem, $items.get( idx ) );
},
getContent = function( callback ) {
  $currentItem.data("container").load( buildUrl(), callback );
},
showContent = function() {
  $currentItem.data("container").show();
  hideContent();
},
hideContent = function() {
  $currentItem.siblings().each(function() {
    $( this ).data("container").hide();
  });
};
$items.each( createContainer ).click( showItem );

return {
  showItemByIndex: showItemByIndex
};

})();

feature.showItemByIndex( 0 );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can declare variables in multiple statements or only in 1, is your decision. (`var x;var y;` versus `var x,y;`). There is no difference as far as I know.
2. Starts with a $ : is at the developers choice, for PHP programmers it lookes better, does not affect the variables, is nothing special, just a naming convention. I don't use it, and I don't recommend it, it only makes your code look worst, and if you use jQuery will give you more headeaches.
3. see point 1 (it has "var", but it is at the begining of the statement) :

   var createContainer = function() {...},buildUrl = function() { ... },showItem = function() {... },showItemByIndex = function( idx ) {...}...;

See more details at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp and http://www.wikihow.com/Declare-a-Variable-in-Javascript